# Threads getting mixed up

Tags: java, multithreading

My threads are getting mixed up. The result of `sendResult()` and `receiveResponse()` should both have different responses (I respond with JSON in a servlet).
However they both reply with the response of `sendResult()`.

Can someone explain why this is, and how to solve this?

```
class Authenticate {
    String t2RequestId = null;
    String finalUserInput = null;

    public synchronized String sendAuthentication(String deviceId, String requestId, String apiKey) {
        // Send notification
        GCM gcmClass = new GCM();
        gcmClass.authenticateRequest(deviceId, requestId, apiKey);

        while(!t2RequestId.equals(requestId)) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return finalUserInput;
    }

    public synchronized void receiveAuthentication(String userInput, String requestId) {
        finalUserInput = userInput;
        t2RequestId = requestId;
        notifyAll();
    }
}

class T1 implements Runnable {
    Authenticate m;
    private final String deviceId;
    private final String requestId;
    private final String apiKey;
    String result;
    public T1(Authenticate m1, String deviceId, String requestId, String apiKey) {
        this.m = m1;
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.requestId = requestId;
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        Thread t1 = new Thread(this, requestId);
        t1.start();

        // Wait for thread to finish before sending response
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
       result = m.sendAuthentication(deviceId, requestId, apiKey);
    }
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}

class T2 implements Runnable {
    Authenticate m;
    private final String requestId;
    private final String userInput;
    public T2(Authenticate m2, String requestId, String userInput) {
        this.m = m2;
        this.requestId = requestId;
        this.userInput = userInput;
        Thread t2 = new Thread(this, "t2" + requestId);
        t2.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        m.receiveAuthentication(userInput, requestId);
    }
}
public class AuthenticationHandler {
    final static Authenticate m = new Authenticate();

    public static String sendRequest(String deviceId, String requestId, String apiKey) {
        T1 runnable = new T1(m, deviceId, requestId, apiKey);
        String result = runnable.getResult();
        return result;
    }
    public static void receiveResponse(String requestId, String userInput) {
        new T2(m, requestId, userInput);
    }
}
```

Comment: There ar some cases that i didn't not understand.
T1 initilized and main thread waits for the T1 thread.
But T1 thread waits for response so T2 can not run.
Where do you call sendRequest and receiveResponse?

Comment: Are you sure you got response from servlet?
Also notify is not a good solution because it notifies a thread randomly. For example you have 30 thread waiting and you call a notify then you choose a thread randomly

Comment: Also your classes held states that can be a big problem.

Comment: @user3087839 sendRequest and receiveResponse are both called when the servlet receives a JSON request. I am getting a response from the servlet only both requests get the same response what shouldn't happen. Is there a way I can call a specific thread, maybe by name? I ain't that far in programming yet, have been trying for around a month now so I have no idea what "classes holding state" means... Could you elaborate?

Comment: @user3087839 I have updated the code so I think now it should notify all threads however only if requestId matches it will continue.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735601/what-is-stateless-object-in-java) contains a succinct summary of stateful vs statelessness.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking.  There's way too much code here, you could eliminate probably half and still demonstrate the behavior you're interested in.  Also, `Runnable` objects should not create their own threads.  You should call `run` directly, or pass it into a thread or executor.  It's especially inappropriate to do so in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a better(?) way to handle the thread communication I think, for the interested:

Global variable:

```
TreeMap<String, String> confirmResult = new TreeMap<String, String>();
```

First thread:

```
    Thread.currentThread().setName(requestId);
    try
    {
        synchronized(Thread.currentThread())
        {
            switch(serviceType)
            {
                case "GCM":
                    // Send notification to android device
                    GCM gcmClass = new GCM();
                    gcmClass.authenticateRequest(deviceId, requestId, apiKey);
                    break;
            }
            // Wait for reply
            Thread.currentThread().wait();
        }
        synchronized(this)
        {
            if(confirmResult.containsKey(requestId))
            {
                // Get the result
                String result = confirmResult.get(requestId);

                // Process the result
                switch(result)
                {
                    case "approved":
                        jsonResponse.setResult(0);
                        jsonResponse.setResultText("approved");
                        break;
                    case "cancelled":
                        jsonResponse.setResult(10000);
                        jsonResponse.setResultText("cancelled");
                        break;
                }
                // Remove the key from the TreeMap
                confirmResult.remove(requestId);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Second thread:

```
    synchronized(this)
    {
        // Put the result in the TreeMap
        confirmResult.put(requestId, confirmation);
    }
    // Get a list of all threads
    Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> arr = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
    // List the threads
    for(Map.Entry<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> entry : arr.entrySet())
    {
        // Check if the notify thread still exists
        if(entry.getKey().getName().equals(requestId))
        {
            synchronized(entry.getKey())
            {
                // Notify the thread
                entry.getKey().notify();
            }
        }
    }
```