# Executing multiple machines in parallel in thread safe manner

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, executorservice

I have a list of hostname which I am executing in parallel using `ExecutorService` to collect all the metrics for each hostname. And then I am making a List which has all the metrics related information for all the hostnames by iterating each hostnames future. Since I am executitng multiple hostnames in parallel so I am not sure whether this code is thread safe or not.

This is my main code where I am executing multiple `HOSTNAMES` in parallel:

```
final Flows typeOfFlow = Flows.TREE;

List<Future<MachineMetrics>> machineFutureList = new ArrayList<>();
for (final String machine : HOSTNAMES) {
    machineFutureList.add(executorService.submit(new Callable<MachineMetrics>() {
        @Override
        public MachineMetrics call() throws Exception {
            MachineMetrics machineMetrics = new MachineMetrics();
            String url = "http://" + machine + ":8080/text";
            Map<String, String> metrics = getMetrics(machine, url, typeOfFlow);
            machineMetrics.setMachineName(machine.split("\\.")[0]);
            machineMetrics.setDatacenter(TestUtils.findDatacenter(machine).get().name().toLowerCase());
            machineMetrics.setMetrics(metrics);
            return machineMetrics;
        }
    }));
}
List<MachineMetrics> metricsList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Future<MachineMetrics> future : machineFutureList) {
    try {
        metricsList.add(future.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        // log exception here
    }
}
// now print all the hostnames metrics information
System.out.println(metricsList);
```

And below is my `getMetrics` code in the same class where my above code is there:

```
private Map<String, String> getMetrics(final String machine, final String url, final Flows flowType) {
    Map<String, String> holder = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = RestTemplateClient.getInstance().getClient();
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
        Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(response);
        while (m.find()) {
            String key = m.group(1).trim();
            String value = m.group(2).trim();
            holder.put(key, value);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // log here
    }

    return TestUtils.process(holder);
}
```

And below is my `findDatacenter` code in `TestUtils` class:

```
public static Optional<Datacenter> findDatacenter(final String hostname) {
    if (!TestUtils.isEmpty(hostname)) {
        for (Datacenter dc : DC_LIST) {
            String namepart = "." + dc.name().toLowerCase() + ".";
            if (hostname.indexOf(namepart) >= 0) {
                return Optional.of(dc);
            }
        }
    }
    return Optional.absent();
}
```

And below is my `process` method in `TestUtils` class:

```
public static Map<String, String> process(final Map<String, String> holder) {
    Map<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : holder.entrySet()) {
        if (!entry.getKey().startsWith("calls_") && !entry.getValue().contains("|")) {
            continue;
        }
        String currentKey = entry.getKey();
        String currentValue = entry.getValue();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(currentValue, "|");

        String count = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();
        String avgData = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();
        String medianData = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();
        String n95data = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();
        String n99data = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();

        tempMap.put(generateKey(currentKey, currentKey.contains(MISS), COUNT), count);
        tempMap.put(generateKey(currentKey, currentKey.contains(MISS), AVG_IN_MS), avgData);
        tempMap.put(generateKey(currentKey, currentKey.contains(MISS), MEDIAN_IN_MS), medianData);
        tempMap.put(generateKey(currentKey, currentKey.contains(MISS), N95_IN_MS), n95data);
        tempMap.put(generateKey(currentKey, currentKey.contains(MISS), N99_IN_MS), n99data);

        holder.remove(currentKey);
    }

    tempMap.putAll(holder);

    return tempMap;
}
```

And below is my `generateKey` method in `TestUtils` class:

```
private static String generateKey(final String currentKey, final boolean hasMiss, final String constant) {
    StringBuilder newKey = new StringBuilder();

    if (hasMiss) {
        newKey.append(currentKey).append(constant);
    } else {
        String firstPart = currentKey.substring(0, currentKey.indexOf("_"));
        String secondPart = currentKey.substring(currentKey.lastIndexOf("_") + 1, currentKey.length());
        newKey.append(firstPart).append(CACHE).append(secondPart).append(constant);
    }

    return newKey.toString();
}
```

And below is my `MachineMetrics` class:

```
public class MachineMetrics {

    private String machineName;
    private String datacenter;
    private Map<String, String> metrics;

    // normal setters and getters here
}
```

Is my above code thread safe? Am I doing anything wrong by which I may be seeing wrong results because of some race conditions or thread safety issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good. Your methods are [stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735601/what-is-stateless-object-in-java). Also you use [immutable objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html) as methods params. So you will have no problem with thread safety.

One remark:

```
for (Future<MachineMetrics> future : machineFutureList) {
    try {
        metricsList.add(future.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        // log exception here
    }
}
```

[get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) `Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.` So if first call was slow, you will not retrieve other results. Use [isDone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()) to check that you can call `get` without waiting.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you provide an example how will I use `isDone` method here along with `get` call? I am slightly confuse here.

Comment: And also in some of my methods, I do have `static` in my `TestUtils` class. Is that ok? Since I am using those methods from the code which is multithreaded.

Comment: It's ok to use `static`. Because method is not synchronized and not use any shared state.

Comment: Here is example with `isDone` call:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.ru/2015/01/how-to-use-future-and-futuretask-in-Java.html