# Is a class without fields thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

If I make a class with only methods and no variables, with each method having its own local variable then, will that class be thread-safe? for eg.

```
   public class Client {

                public String xyz(final String inputXML) {
                      DataInputStream dis = null;
                      DataOutputStream dout = null;
                      Socket clientSocket = null;
                        //do some processing 
                    }

                public String abc(final String inputXML) {
                      DataInputStream dis = null;
                      DataOutputStream dout = null;
                      Socket clientSocket = null;
                        //do some processing 
                    }
        }
```

now if I launch multiple threads of this Client then, will the class be thread safe ?

Comment: It is thread safe, but if you try to open the same socket from multiple threads you will still get concurrency issues.

Comment: It is not the same Socket because there is no share data between different calls to those methods. If a new Socket is created in each thread it works on a different port on the client side so no data is mixed between socket connections. A socket is identified by the ip, port of the server and ip, port of the client. The port of the client changes in this case

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9735625/545127

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes your class is thread safe.

A method is thread safe if:

- has no access to shared variables
- Access to shared immutable variables
- Access to variables which state can be modified only in a thread safe manner (for example via synchronized methods)
- Access to variables with a synchronized block using the same lock of other threads that use the same variable

Your methods haven't access to shared variables so are thread safe

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically yes, practically it depends on the values of your variables if they are independent instances or if they point to the same instances somewhere in the system