# Java - Can't use HttpServlet 's methods for retrieving data for a request when using @Stateless

Tags: java, servlets

I created a web service on which I used @Stateless annotation i.e

```
 @Stateless
 @Path("/boo/too")
 public class RestController {

@Context 
private HttpServletRequest request;

@Context
private ServletContext context;


@GET
@Path("/coo")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public GetResObj getFuncName(
        @HeaderParam("foo") String foo,
        @QueryParam("boo") String boo
        ) throws Exception{ 

    MyClass className =(ClassCast) request.getSession().getAttribute("myClassInstance");
}
```

Now from some reading i have done and the accurate answer to this question :
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735601/what-is-stateless-object-in-java)

, I understand that a Stateless object is an object which can have variables but it's immutable (can't hold any state). When using the @Stateless annotation the `request.getSession()` part of code throws a nullPointerException . When i remove the @Stateless annotation the `request.getSession()` works fine .

Can you see why is this happening ?

Comment: Just a guess - you might try to pass the request as context parameter to the method - someting like `@GET
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Path("search")
 public Something searchDbViews(

   @Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context SecurityContext sec, ...
`

Comment: @GyroGearless .So how should i try to pass it instead of context ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems HttpServletRequest instance didn't get injected into request field ever.

Can you check injecting HttpServletRequest into resource method parameter list e.g. final @Context HttpServletRequest request.