# How can i check for duplicate items in a List<string>?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
private void test(List<string> a)
{

}
```

I want to use for in for loop's and to check that if there are duplicated items in the List a 
Then mark it with null.

Comment: What do you mean by "mark it with null"?

Comment: You might as well not have posted any code at all, as what you did post is meaningless. Voting to close this as "not a real question", as it shows zero effort to solve the problem yourself, and no research at all before posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want to do here but if you wanted to just get a collection of the distinct values in the list you could use LINQ to do this:

```
var distinctOnes = a.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the strings and put new strings in a HashSet so that you can efficiently check for repeats:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++) {
  if (set.Contains(a[i])) {
    // duplicate
    a[i] = null;
  } else {
    set.Add(a[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really avoid methods with side effects [Side Effects Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1073932/809314). You can achieve what you want like this:

```
private List<String> test(List<String> originalList)
{
    List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String value : originalList)
    {
        if (!returnList.contains(value))
        {
            returnList.add(value);
        }
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

You can easily amend this method to add null as well if you really wanted to (instead of not adding anything if its already been added)...

Comment: Rather than the (particularly inefficient) method, you could just use `return originalList.Distinct()`;

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool HasDuplicates(List<string> a)
{
    return a.Distinct().Count() != a.Count();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use LINQ

```
var list = (from n in a select n).Distinct().ToList();
```

so know you have a unique list that you can check against "a"

Comment: why do you have an identity select at the start of the query?  Just call `list.Distinct()`.