# Problem when using Shiny app to save the data

Tags: r, shiny, save

I have a shiny app which has many text inputs. I could not get the save data part right, for example, to save to a local drive. Any suggestions?

```
     server = function(input, output) {
      values <- reactiveValues()
      #Initial Dataframe 
      values$df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=4,nrow=0, dimnames=list(NULL, c("Name", "date","Traning",  "certificate"))))

      FinalData =observe({
        if(input$submit >0) {
        isolate(values$df <- rbind(values$df,data.frame("name" = input$name,"date" = input$date, 
                           "training" = input$training, "certificate" = input$certificate)))
    # saveRDS(values$df)
    # saveRDS(FinalData)
                   }})

    #display the inputs
     output$Combined_table = renderDataTable({values$df})
}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this demonstration:

```r
library(shiny)
.log <- function(...) message(format(Sys.time(), format = "[ %H:%M:%S ]"), " ", ...)
.read <- function(path) if (file.exists(path)) return(readRDS(path))
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textInput("txt", "Text: "),
    actionButton("btn", "Submit"),
    tableOutput("tbl")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    .log("hello world")
    rv <- reactiveValues()
    rv$df <- data.frame(row = 0L, word = "a", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[0,]
    observeEvent(req(input$btn), {
      .log("submit!")
      rv$df <- rbind(rv$df,
                     data.frame(row = input$btn, word = input$txt,
                                stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
      .log("saveRDS: ", nrow(rv$df))
      saveRDS(rv$df, "local.rds")
    })
    filedata <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session, "local.rds", .read)
    output$tbl <- renderTable(filedata())
  }
)
```

[image: sample shiny app]

The engineering of this app:

- I use a `reactiveValues` like you did, in order to keep the in-memory data. (Note: iteratively adding rows to a frame is bad in the long-run. If this is low-volume adding, then you're probably fine, but it scales badly. Each time a row is added, it copies the entire frame, doubling memory consumption.)
- I pre-fill the `$df` with a zero-row frame, just for formatting. Nothing fancy here.
- `observe` and `observeEvent` do not return something you are interested in, it should be operating completely by [*side-effect*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1073909/3358272). It does return something, but it is really only meaningful to `shiny` internals.
- `saveRDS` as you do, nothing fancy, but it works.
- I added a [`shiny::reactiveFileReader`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveFileReader.html) in order to demonstrate that the file was being saved. When the shiny table shows an update, it's because (1) the data was added to the underlying frame; (2) the frame was saved to the `"local.rds"` file; then (3) `reactiveFileReader` noticed that the underlying file exists and has changed, causing (4) it to call my `.read` function to read the contents and return it as reactive data into `filedata`. This block is completely unnecessary in general, just for demonstration here.
- I create a function `.read` for this `reactiveFileReader` that is resilient to the file not existing first. If the file does not exist, it invisibly returns `NULL`. There may be better ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks r2evans. I was wondering if it will be working when upload the app to server, especially in same case some people may use the app at same time. Is there a chance that the inputs from one person may override the inputs from other people? let me try your code.

Comment: Yes that's possible. It sounds like you need something like a database or redis (or similar) server to handle concurrent access. If you're talking just a few at a time, you might be able to use sqlite (or duckdb) instead.

Comment: I have been reading "Persistent data storage with Shiny" by Deam Attali.  He mentioned some remote solutions.  I do not know if it works with microsoft SQL server which I have access

Comment: With a DBMS available, you can certainly make this more amenable to multiple users. I suggest you create a table that hold all of your information (plus, perhaps, an `Id` field, others might be useful), and `DBI::dbWriteTable(..., append=TRUE)` that information. Instead of `reactiveFileReader`, if you need to periodically check, then `observe({..., invalidateLater(3000);})` will re-trigger the block every 3 seconds (tune to your needs, realizing it's running a query every time, definitely ways to do this wrong and right).

Comment: (1) Dean is smart and talented. (2) DBMS is a good way to go, good reading to start talking "database access" (if you haven't already started): [`DBI`](https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI), [`odbc`](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc), and [RStudio's "DB" stuff](https://db.rstudio.com/).

Comment: r2evans, I tried your way using observeEvent(req(input$btn) which solve one of my bugs. My code will save the data without click submit button when I change name text input after previous submit button clicked (may be because if(input$submit >0)) i guess. what is "req" after oberveEvent ? what it does? Thanks

Comment: If it (my code) saves the data without pressing the submit button, then either (1) you've changed something in the code, or (2) `shiny` has failed. The use of `observeEvent(req(input$btn), ...)` "guarantees" that the only thing that can trigger saving the data is `input$btn`. For your second question, see [`?req`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/req.html).

Comment: that "guarantees" is what I am looking for.  Appreciate !