# React: need some help understand strict mode and what what qualifies as a side effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I encountered a weird bug in React the other day and this is the simplified version of it.

```js
let count = 0;
export default function App() {
  const [countState, setCountState] = useState(count);
  const [countState2, setCountState2] = useState(count);
  const increaseCount1 = () => ++count;

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCountState(() => increaseCount1());
  };
  const handleClick2 = () => {
    setCountState2(() => countState2 + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{countState}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Btn1</button>
      <div>
        <h1>{countState2}</h1>
        <button onClick={handleClick2}>Btn2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the live demo https://codesandbox.io/s/side-effect-ryfwr

when `Btn1`  got clicked on, `countState` will increase by 2 not by 1, while when `Btn2` got clicked on, `countState2` will increase by 1, which is expected. I was struggling to understand what caused `countState` to increase by 2. Then I figured it out it has something to do with [React's strict mode.](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) It is mentioned in the article that Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer can be doubled invoked to detect side effects. Given that, I think what I have passed in `setCountState` is a side effect i.e. `setCountState(() => increaseCount1());`

But I still don't quite understand why `setCountState(() => increaseCount1());` is a side effect while `setCountState2(() => countState2 + 1);` is fine. I need a mental model. Can someone help me understand this more deeply?

Comment: `increaseCount1` changing `count` is a [side-effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073909/side-effect-whats-this) and because of `StrictMode`, it is incrementing `count` twice. You should update the state using the current state: `setCountState((currentState) => currentState + 1)`

Comment: Generally, side effects of functions are anything the function does that directly changes anything outside the function. So, a function is allowed to receive data via its args or context and emit data via `return`, but that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see how the mutation works, or is exposed, lets compare both implementations.

First example:

> ```
> const increaseCount1 = () => ++count;
>
> const handleClick = () => {
>   setCountState(() => increaseCount1());
> };
> ```

Assume `countState`  and `count` are `0`, when React double invokes `setCountState` this is what occurs:

```
setCountState(() => increaseCount1());
// (1) increaseCount1 invoked
// (2) ++count -> count incremented from 0 to 1
// (3) setCountState called with 1
setCountState(() => increaseCount1());
// (1) increaseCount1 invoked
// (2) ++count -> count incremented from 1 to 2
// (3) setCountState called with 2
```

Result is `countState` now is `2`.

Second example:

> ```
> const handleClick2 = () => {
>   setCountState2(() => countState2 + 1);
> };
> ```

Assume `countState2` and `count` are `0`, when React double invokes `setCountState2` this is what occurs:

```
setCountState2(() => countState2 + 1);
// (1) countState2 + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
// (2) setCountState2 called with 1
setCountState2(() => countState2 + 1);
// (1) countState2 + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
// (2) setCountState2 called with 1
```

Result is `countState2` now is only `1`.

## Conclusion

When the ***next*** state necessarily depends on the ***previous*** state you should use a functional state update that references from the previous state (passed as an argument). Incrementing a count is the actual prototypical React example for functional state updates.

```
setCount(count => count + 1)
```

Here the *next* count is incremented from the previous state's value.